# ACF repeater field

Tags: plugins

I’m wondering how to display, in the backoffice, only the 20 last field according to their post_id DESC.

A group of field generated contain a date and value. I guess in the database there’s post_id corresponding for each group and want to sort it following it.

I used the max row =20, but i could not found where to specify that i need it sorted by post_id DESC.

In the picture i'm aiming to display it as :
24/12/2013  8

23/12/2013  99

20/12/2013  10

Thank you a lot !

[image]

Comment: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-sorting-a-repeater-field/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in this case, in which file I should add the code ?

Comment: I don't know your theme. It would be the template that displays that content. But honestly, if you don't know where this code goes, you probably shouldn't be fiddling with it.